# Images in RecyclerView feels laggy (Using Picasso)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a RecyclerView (It is actually a chat). The users can send images and text. The problem is when I scroll it feels laggy because the images are being loaded (If I go down and up, it takes to much time to Picasso to bring the image back again). And I'm using this line of code to do it.

```
 Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(((ChatMediaMessage) message).getUrl())
                    .into(imageView);
```

If I use the resize option is not laggy at all, but the images lose the image ratio obviously.

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(((ChatMediaMessage) message).getUrl())
                    .resize(400, 400)
                    .into(imageView);
```

The layout of the ViewHolder looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <com.stfalcon.chatkit.utils.ShapeImageView
        android:id="@id/messageUserAvatar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@id/bubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_incoming_bubble_margin_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messageUserAvatar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:justifyContent="flex_end">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/messageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/messageText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_alignSelf="center" />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try Glide? Give it a try. Just add the library on dependencies and only replace the Picasso word.

Is your image size bigger, like 2Mb above? Try resizing or optimizing the image before upload it anywhere.

Is your image JPG? You can use RIOT http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/
to optimize your JPG/PNG.

Or it's advisable to convert your JPG images into WebP. Android Studio has the built in converter to try. WebP loads faster and smaller in size.

Comment: I can not use RIOT because the user is the one who uploads the image through the chat. And they are not bigger than 1 MB.

Comment: Already give a try to Glide? Im using Picasso too before Glide, in fact Picasso will loads everytime you open the activity. Glide has cache capability which it stores some of image data inside phone storage and call it back later, saving some data.

Comment: I have not use Glide. Let me try it.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use adjustViewBounds for dynamically-loaded images, because it will trigger a full relayout after each image completes loading. Set a fixed size to your `ImageView`s instead, and use `centerInside` scale mode if you want to preserve aspect ratio, or `centerCrop` if you prefer to crop the image. This tip applies to any image library.

Furthermore, when the `ImageView` has a fixed size, Picasso or Glide allows you to resize the image to it automatically, which reduces memory usage and improves performance. For **Picasso**, use:

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(((ChatMediaMessage) message).getUrl())
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
```

You can also use `centerInside()` instead of `centerCrop()`.

Glide has a similar API. It will provide slightly better performance than Picasso because it caches the resized images to disk as well, while Picasso only caches the full-size images to disk and will have to resize them each time they are loaded back from disk.